# r shiny create dropdown menu using folder content

Tags: r, drop-down-menu, shiny

This is my day one with R shiny and I'm trying to figure out the following question: assuming that I have a root directory like

```
/usr/data/
```

This directory might contain some folders (A,B,C,...) where each folder has contains some files (no folders within them and just files). I am planning to create a dropdown menue based on another dropdown menu. The use select a folder name from the list and the second dropdown menu is automatically loaded with the file names within that folder. For example if folder `A` is selected and it contains `File1` and `File2` then the second dropdown will contain those two. This is how I'm doing it right now:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("This is a test app"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("Box1"),
      uiOutput("Box2")
    ),
    mainPanel("Display results",
              tableOutput("view"))
  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
biz = data.frame(
  Folder = c("A", "A", "B" , "B"), 
  Filename = c("File1","File2","File3","File4"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  output$Box1 = renderUI(selectInput("folder","Select directory",c("None",unique(biz$Folder)),"None"))


  output$Box2 = renderUI(
    if (is.null(input$folder) || input$folder == "None"){return()
    }else selectInput("filename", 
                      "Select dataset", 
                      c("None",unique(biz$Filename[which(biz$Folder == input$folder)])),
                      "None")
  )


  subdata1 = reactive(biz[which(biz$Folder == input$folder),])
  subdata2 = reactive(subdata1()[which(subdata1()$Filename == input$filename),])

  output$view = renderTable({
    if(is.null(input$folder) || is.null(input$filename)){return()
    } else if (input$folder == "None" || input$filename == "None"){return()

    } else return(subdata2())
  })

})
```

As you can see, I'm using a dataframe to take care of that but this should better be dynamic in case that the content of those folders change. So I think the best way is to have list of folder names and then get the contents of that folder and load them in to the second dropdown. I have tried several posts on SO but they are mostly about the content of a csv file and so on. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend generating UI elements reactively in the following way:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("My Great File Selector"),

  fluidRow(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("select.folder"),
      uiOutput('select.file')
    )
  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  root <- '~'

  output$select.folder <-
    renderUI(expr = selectInput(inputId = 'folder.name',
                                label = 'Folder Name',
                                choices = list.dirs(path = root,
                                                    full.names = FALSE,
                                                    recursive = FALSE)))

  output$select.file <-
    renderUI(expr = selectInput(inputId = 'file.name',
                                label = 'File Name',
                                choices = list.files(path = file.path(root,
                                                                      input$folder.name))))

})
```

All I have done in ui.R is essentially promise that I will render two UI elements named 'select.folder' and 'select.file' in server.R.  That's pretty simple.

In server.R, I specify `root`, where I want the app to look for directories.

I use `renderUI()` to generate a UI element in which the user will select the folder and store it in `output$select.folder`, fulfilling my first promise in ui.R, give it a label of 'Folder Name', and set its choices to the result of `list.dirs()` (from base R) called with the appropriate arguments.  The choice that the user has selected in this UI element will be accessible via `input$folder.name` because the InputId is `'folder.name'`.

I use `renderUI()` again to generate a UI element that will be used to select a file in that folder and store it in `output$select.file`, fulfilling my second promise from ui.R.  Its choices are based on a call to `list.files` that uses the folder selected in the first UI element, retrieving it via `input$folder.name'.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to up vote your answer but thanks for detailed explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the names of the files in a folder with the `list.files` function.

So something like this should work:

```
ROOT <- '/usr/data'
dropdown_options <- list.files(paste(ROOT, input$folder, sep = '/'))
```